# .htaccess rewrite for a simpleton

Tags: .htaccess

I can generally figure this kind of thing out on my own, but I'm totally lost on how to write a rewrite rule in .htaccess

my current url looks like:

index.php?p=page&v=2&i=2&pg=01

I'm trying to make the url look like this:

/vol2/iss2/pg01/

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^vol([0-9]+)/iss([0-9]+)/pg([0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=page&v=$1&i=$2&pg=$3
```

Comment: this is what i'm looking for, but since these php variables generate the page content, i'm not sure how to make this new url pass the variables the way the old url does... is it possible?

Comment: nevermind works perfect just had to relink my stylesheet properly, thanks so much